# how to compare enum values

Tags: c, enums

I have a question about `enum` C.

I defined an `enum` in the following way:

```
typedef enum
{
    Hello1 = 1,
    Hello2 = 2,
    Hello3 = 3
}Hello

Hello hello;

int value = 3;
```

then how to compare the value with the value in `Hello`?

for example:

```
if(value == Hello3)
{
}
```

or should I do it like the following:

```
if(value == Hello.Hello3)
{
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This way is correct:

```
 if (value == Hello3)
 {
 }
```

`enum` constants are of type `int`.

Your second construct is invalid.

Answer (score 6):

`enum` is not a structure and the member names are just names of the corresponding `constants`.
These names defined in `enum` are not the data members of `enum` like in `struct` (as you are thinking).

So remember `enum` are used to define a list of named integer constants which we can do using `#define` also.

So here in your case:

```
if(value == Hello3)
{
}
```

This is the correct way to compare as it replaces `Hello3` by the value `3` (which is nothing but `int`) at compile time.

For example you can do it also like this:

```
Hello hello=2;
if(hello == Hello2)
{
}
```